# Can I make the TeXShop edior look like Overleaf?

Tags: overleaf, texshop, themes

I've just begun using TeXshop in order to write without wifi, but I've come across an aesthetic problem.
On Overleaf, the "editor themes" give different colours for commands, environments, and normal mathmode text. However in TeXShop there is only one colour for commands and environments, and text written in mathmode is the same colour as text outside mathmode.

Is there any way to change the TeXShop theme to match the themes I'm used to in Overleaf (specifically the "textmate" theme)?

Comment: Welcome to TSE!

Comment: If you select `TeXShop` -> `Settings` -> `Themes` you can configure themes to your heart's content.

Comment: @LaTeXereXeTaL, as far as I can tell this only allows you to change the theme's colour for all mathmode text (i.e the commands, environments will be the same colour, and the text will be the same colour in and outside of mathmode). Is there a way to configure these seperately?

Comment: Not to my knowledge unfortunately.